# How to add title on Magento 2 Block

Tags: magento, magento2

How to add a title on Magneto 2 Block something like from tag {{}}. I want to replace "PAGE TITLE FROM TAG" and want to make it dynamic.

```
<div class="item" >
  <div class="ban ban-effect-1">
    <img class="image" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/services/title_slim.jpg"}}" 
         alt="Some Title here" />
    <div class="cap cap-center-vertically cap-center-horizontally cap-no-bg">
        <h3 class="text" data-animate-in="fadeInRight"> PAGE TITLE FROM TAG</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to custom phtml template file, right?

If yes, you can use this function:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
```

with your case, you can add the dynamic content like this:

```
<h3 class="text" data-animate-in="fadeInRight"><?=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle()?></h3>
```

Comment: Is this will work under block ? Its showing like this <!-- ?php $this--! getLayout() -> getBlock('head') -> getTitle() ?>